# is there a way to store video on an external device yet be able to edit it in iMovie on my ipad air?

Tags: imovie, storage, ipad, video-editing

I have an ipad air and recently i was trying to edit a quick 10 min movie of some 1080p 60fps video in iMovie. I only have a 32 gig ipad air so i wasn't able to upload all the video on to the ipad. i had to purchased icloud storage upgrade for a month so i could download the video i needed to work with in imovie. This wasnt a great solution as i would download the video i wanted to edit then delete the video so i can download more. I was wondering if there was a way to hold the videos on an external drive, laptop or any other method so that i can work on my ipad and then export to that drive or laptop? Any better solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you need to purchase iCloud Storage? Your videos are stored locally in the Photos app, until you copy them into iMovie.

Comment: With only 2 to 5 gigs free of storage on my ipad i couldn't fit the 20 gigs of video i needed to work with. Luckily iCloud is well integrated into iMovie and i was able to pay 99¢ to store the all the videos on iCloud then download the clip i wanted to work with, delete after i wad done working with it, and lastly repeat until i was finished with the movie.